# How to display specific columns from excel to C# datagridview

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

Im having trouble displaying specific columns from excel to c# in data grid view. i dont know what is the syntax to display specific columns. im using oledb for displaying da data.

Here's my code:

```
    private void WorkOrderTab()
    {
        string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(WOmain);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
        string conStr, sheetName;
        conStr = string.Empty;
        //Get the name of the First Sheet.
        using (OleDbConnection kuneksyon = new OleDbConnection(Excel07ConString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand utos = new OleDbCommand())
            { 
                using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                {
                utos.Connection = kuneksyon;
                kuneksyon.Open();
                DataTable dtExcelSchema = kuneksyon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                kuneksyon.Close();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                utos.Connection = kuneksyon;
                utos.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
                kuneksyon.Open();
                oda.SelectCommand = utos;
                oda.Fill(dt);
                kuneksyon.Close();
                //Populate DataGridView.
                WorkLoadDisp.DataSource = dt;
                label1.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your worksheet has HEADERS in its first row, those headers are the column names, if no headers then the column names are automatically named F1, F2, Fn. Then it is just SELECT colname1, colname2, colname3 FROM .....

Comment: Thanks sir steve for the information. it helped a lot. heres what i did: utos.CommandText = "SELECT [Column name1] From [" + sheetName + "]";

Comment: Is this question about ASP.NET or is it a WinForm/WPF app?

Comment: its a winform. whats the difference between asp.net and winform . sorry im new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Create Bound fields in the frontend when you assign datasurce and bind it. The row with header ln will automatically bind with the first column and fn to second one. set `Autogeneratecolumns="false"` in `datagridview`.

```
       <asp:BoundField DataField="ln" HeaderText="LastName"/>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="fn" HeaderText="FirstName"/>
```

Comment: What make you think that this question is about ASP.NET?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, perhaps this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793990/how-to-show-only-certain-columns-in-a-datagridview-with-custom-objects