# C# Show Entity Model's Specific Columns on DataGrid

Tags: c#, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am use ADO.NET Entity Data Model in my desktop application.And I want show my table's datas on dataGridView.But only specified columns.

For Example ;

Columns Of My Table = (ID,Number,Phone,Location,CreateDate,CreateUser)

I want show only (Number,Phone,Location) on dataGridView.

My Record :

```
ID = 1
Number = 123
Phone = 078424
Location = Turkey
CreateDate = 2020-03-09
CreateUser = admin
```

My Data Grid will show :

```
Number    Phone         Location
-------   ----------    ---------
123       078424        Turkey
```

Comment: What is your question, where did you get stuck?

Comment: `dataGrid.source = entity.MyTable.ToList()`   get all columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show only certain columns in a DataGridView with custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793990/how-to-show-only-certain-columns-in-a-datagridview-with-custom-objects)