# Would it be possible `ToBindingList` few selected properties from Entity and it's InverseProperty?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

appreciate your help and patience here! as I am a newbie to this and open to any new suggestion to achieve this!

So I have an Entity `Candidate` which references another Entity `Candimmigration`. I would like to Bind a few properties "NOT all Properties" from `Candidate` and  `Candimmigration` into a Datagrid view, therefore if the data changes, the datagridview data get updated automatically.

```
  public partial class Candidate
  {
            [Key]
            [Column("ID")]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [StringLength(20)]
            public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
            [StringLength(20)]
            public string? MiddleName { get; set; }
            [StringLength(20)]
            public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
            [Column(TypeName = "date")]
            public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
            [StringLength(6)]
            public string? Gender { get; set; }
            // more properties 
    
            [InverseProperty("Candidate")]
            public virtual Candimmigration Candimmigration { get; set; } = null!;
           // more InverseProperties
    }
```

---

```
 public partial class Candimmigration
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CandidateId { get; set; }
        public string? VisaNo{ get; set; }
        public string? PassportNo { get; set; }
        public string? PlaceOfBirth { get; set; }
        // more properties 
}
```

---

I would like to bind and show only the below properties in the datagridview. Is there a way to achieve this rather than creating a list `.ToList`, then I have to recreate it every time data changes to refresh/reload the datagridview. Any suggestions for implementation, please?

```
Candidate.Id
Candidate.FirstName
Candidate.LastName
Candimmigration.VisaNo
```

The code below binds all `Candidates` to the grid view , which is not the expected result.

```
_dbContext.Candidates.Load();
_dbContext.Candidates.Local.ToBindingList();
```

[image]

Comment: Why don’t you just define the columns in the datagridview instead of relying on the autogenerated columns?

Comment: Here you may find some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793990/how-to-show-only-certain-columns-in-a-datagridview-with-custom-objects

Comment: Or this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/add-and-remove-columns-in-the-datagrid-using-the-designer?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @RandRandom, thank you for the comments. But how can I display ‘Candimmigration.VisaNo’ as column in the data grid view, as of know it’s loading Candimmigration object as column

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683796/winforms-datagridview-databind-to-complex-type-nested-property

Comment: @RandRandom can’t add a property to the entity class as those are autogenerated by scaffolding from database. And I cannot do LINQ projection as then it won’t be binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`And I cannot do LINQ projection as then it won’t be binding`

this statement is only true, if you are using an anonymous type

no one is stopping you from projecting your type to a "bindable" type

something like this:

```
class CandidateModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;

    public CandimmigrationModel Candimmigration { get; set; } = null!;
}

class CandimmigrationModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? VisaNo{ get; set; }
}

class CandidateViewModel
{
    private CandidateModel _candidateModel;
    private CandimmigrationModel _candimmigrationModel;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get => _candidateModel.FirstName;
        set => _candidateModel.FirstName = value;
    }

    public string VisaNo
    {
        get => _candimmigrationModel.VisaNo;
        set => _candimmigrationModel.VisaNo= value;
    }

    public CandidateViewModel(CandidateModel candidateModel, CandimmigrationModel candimmigrationModel)
    {

    }
}
```

to project to this type simple add

```
.Select(x => new CandidateViewModel(x, x.Candimmigration))
```

Comment: thank you. I think I know where you hinting at, so I will give it a try and get back to you.