# System.InvalidOperationException when attempting `.ThenInculde`

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Followed a few examples and tutorials about using `.ThenInculde`. Not sure why I am getting the below error when I run this code.

```
_dbContext.Candidates.Where(i => i.Id == 1)
                     .Include(i => i.Candimmigration)
                     .ThenInclude(i => i.PassportNo)
                     .Load();
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The expression 'i.PassportNo' is
> invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a
> property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared
> on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the
> 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection
> navigation access can be filtered by composing Where,
> OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For
> more information on including related data, see
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393

**Candidate Entity**

```
public partial class Candidate
{   
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string? MiddleName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }


    [InverseProperty("Candidate")]
    public virtual Candimmigration Candimmigration { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

**Candimmigration Entity**

```
public partial class Candimmigration
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("CandidateID")]
    public int CandidateId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(9)]
    public string? PassportNo { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CandidateId")]
    [InverseProperty("Candimmigration")]
    public virtual Candidate Candidate { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Comment: Why should you need to include a simple string? Only navigation properties need to be included. - find the definition of navigation property here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include `PassportNo` - it is not a navigation property. You don't need to include non-navigation properties, they will already be there by default.

Include is for properties that related to data stored in other tables.

`PassportNo` is contained in `Candimmigration` which has already been included so there's no need for any more includes.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, I probably miss understood `.thenInculde`. I am trying to figure out a way to include specific properties to load before i bind to Datagrid view.  Can you please look at this question [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73905836/would-it-be-possible-tobindinglist-2-dbsets-to-one-gridview-and-dispaly-only-f). I appreciate if you can help with write way to implement